# Operator new and delete on Inherited class. Operator delete not executing

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading, new-operator, delete-operator

I was messing around operator overloading and I've noticed that on inherited object, the overloaded operator delete doesn't seem to execute when the inherited object has an operator new overloaded:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class TestAbs {
public:
  TestAbs (void) {
  }
  virtual ~TestAbs (void) noexcept {
  }
};

class Test : public TestAbs {
public:
  Test (void) 
      : TestAbs () {
  }
  ~Test (void) noexcept override {
  } 
  void* operator new (size_t) throw () {
    std::cout << "Overloaded operator new!\n";
    return nullptr;
  }
  void operator delete (void*) noexcept {
    std::cout << "Overloaded operator delete in class: Test!\n";
  }
};

int main() {
    TestAbs* tp = new Test ();
    delete tp;

    return 0;
}
```

The code above has the following output:

```
Overloaded operator new!
```

What happened to the overloaded operator delete?
Thank you all in advance!

Update:
Thank you guys for all the help. It seems like the problem was indeed the nullptr return on the overloaded new.

Comment: Read up on how a [delete expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete) works in relation to class-specific `operator delete` overrides

Comment: Thank you guys so much for all the inputs. I'll look into all the posts in detail after I get some sleep.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting a `nullptr` is always a no-op in C++14 and later. Nothing gets called. To make your example work, you'd need to return a pointer that is not null. For example:

```
void* operator new(size_t) throw()
{
    std::cout << "Overloaded operator new!\n";
    return ::new Test;
}
```

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete):

> If expression evaluates to a null pointer value, no destructors are called, and **the deallocation function is not called**.

The above is for C++14 and later. Up to C++11, the deallocation function might get called. It's implementation-defined:

> If expression evaluates to a null pointer value, no destructors are called, and **the deallocation function may or may not be called** (it's implementation-defined), but the default deallocation functions are guaranteed to do nothing when handed a null pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code *should* work, if you just return an address that isn't null pointer value. To quote the C++ standard:

[[class.free]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.free#4)

> Class-specific deallocation function lookup is a part of general
>   deallocation function lookup ([expr.delete]) and occurs as follows. If
>   the delete-expression is used to deallocate a class object whose
>   static type has a virtual destructor, the deallocation function is the
>   one selected at the point of definition of the dynamic type's virtual
>   destructor ([class.dtor]).

[[class.dtor]/13](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.dtor#13)

> At the point of definition of a virtual destructor (including an
>   implicit definition), the non-array deallocation function is
>   determined as if for the expression delete this appearing in a
>   non-virtual destructor of the destructor's class (see [expr.delete]).
>   If the lookup fails or if the deallocation function has a deleted
>   definition, the program is ill-formed. **[ Note: This assures that a
>   deallocation function corresponding to the dynamic type of an object
>   is available for the delete-expression ([class.free]).  — end note ]**

[[expr.delete]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.delete#6)

> If the value of the operand of the delete-expression is not a null
>   pointer value, the delete-expression will invoke the destructor (if
>   any) for the object or the elements of the array being deleted.

You just set it up in a way that won't invoke anything at the `delete` expression. I fixed it up to forward onto the global operators new and delete, and everything works as expected. [The code is on Coliru Viewer](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/61333b1ddd494fa6).